# Understanding authentication flow in OneDrive with Android and Rest API

Tags: android, rest, oauth-2.0, retrofit, onedrive

I tried implementing a signIn method from the OneDrive API, but I am not sure I correctly understood the workflow.
Basically, on first launch of the app, I want to have both the login window and the "authorise the app to..." window". But then, when the user launches the app again, I would like to be directly connected to the app, without any window.
Instead, with the following code, I keep having the second window (where the user decides to accept the app)

```
@Override
public void signIn() {
     //personal code
    linkingStarted = true;
    signInStatus = SignInStatus.SIGNING_IN;
    activity.setUpWait(R.layout.popup_waitgif_white);
    //end of personal code

    mAuthClient = AuthClientFactory.getAuthClient(activity.getApplication());


    if (mAuthClient.getSession().isExpired() && Util.isConnectedToInternet(activity)) {
        activity.alertOnUIThread("Login again");
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAuthClient.login(activity, SCOPES, mAuthListener);

            }
        });

    } else if (!Util.isConnectedToInternet(activity)) {
        activity.alertOnUIThread(activity.getString(R.string.alert_verifyconnection));

    } else {
        activity.alertOnUIThread("Resigned In OneDrive");
        signInStatus = SignInStatus.SIGNED_IN;


        mAuthClient.initialize(SCOPES, new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthComplete(final AuthStatus status, final AuthSession session, final Object userState) {
                if (status == AuthStatus.CONNECTED) {

                    authToken = session.getAccessToken();
                    oneDriveService = getOneDriveService();

                    signInStatus = SignInStatus.SIGNED_IN;

                } else {
                    authenticationFailure();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Problem connecting");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthError(final AuthException exception, final Object userState) {
                //mAuthClient.login(activity, SCOPES, mAuthListener);
            }
        }, null, authToken);
    }


}
```

and the AuthClientFactory is just this:

```
public class AuthClientFactory {

private static AuthClient authClient;
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "00000000XXXXX";


public static AuthClient getAuthClient(Context context) {
    if (authClient == null)
        authClient = new AuthClient(context, OneDriveOAuthConfig.getInstance(), CLIENT_ID);
    return authClient;
}

}
```

Comment: You might be able to get your existing code off the ground by adding the "wl.offline_access" scope if it is missing

Comment: Nope, it does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have an easier time with the [OneDrive SDK for Android](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android), as authentication is a much simpler process.

```
final MSAAuthenticator msaAuthenticator = new MSAAuthenticator() {
   @Override
   public String getClientId() {
      return "<msa-client-id>";
   }

   @Override
   public String[] getScopes() {
      return new String[] { "onedrive.appfolder", "wl.offline_access"};
   }
}

final IClientConfig oneDriveConfig = new DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticator(msaAuthenticator);
final IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient
                                        .Builder()
                                        .fromConfig(oneDriveConfig)
                                        .loginAndBuildClient(getActivity());
```

That will take care of the user authentication flow and then give you a service object that makes interacting with OneDrive straight-forward.  See the full [example application](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android).

Comment: Actually, I think I start to remember why I had chosen a different approach... The sdk you mention does not seem to allow "view.search" queries, does it?
I remember ending up modifying the example application you are mentioning and using a oauth helper package and a retrofit package for onedrive, but I have a hard time  remembering where I got them from in the first place.

Comment: Search is included in this SDK, it works on items `oneDriveClient.getDrive().getRoot().getSearch("FindThisString")` as

Comment: Nice, I'll test it and upvote your answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working much better :D However, I have problems using the `CountDownLatch()` kind of trick, in order to wait for the callback response before performing the next commands... Indeed, adding a `myCountDownLatch.await()` right after the getSearch() call (with a `myCountDownLatch.countDown()` in the callback) prevents me from getting any answer from OneDrive ... any hint?

Comment: Instead of using a trick, could you just call the synchronous version or use the callback to perform resulting action?

Comment: sorry for the newby question, but how would I call the synchronous version? Thanks.

Comment: When you call getSearch("FindThisString").get(...) if you don't pass in a callback the request is synchronous

Comment: Thanks a lot, You're my savior. I wish I had found a clear documentation somewhere on the net.